The movie in which heroine is kidnapped at beginning and at Ending of the movie where rescuing the heroine, hero had to gave up on his life
Foreword
I watch the movie five or six years before ,It is a colour Korean action-drama sort of movie. And I think, time period (2000 - 2010).
It's some familiar movie but in my native people don't watch Korean movies.I can only remember some particular scene of the movie and storyline.
Plot explanation 
I think - "The Hero arrived late for his wedding and his fiancee(heroine) is kidnapped by some unknown. His life is filled with sorrow , he drunk a lot to forget about his missing lover.
After sometimes, he understands that there are many woman are kidnapped like his fiancee. So some friends who knew how to fight(martial arts) and hero together to find the missing people. 
Climax 
Finally they find all the missed woman and they found who is the responsible for this act. She(Villian) collects the tear drops from the woman she kidnapped and made some precious perfume. Where rescuing the heroine, hero had to gave up on his life(on hanging bridge ). Heroine rescued and Hero died. Thats all I know any ideas? 

You're looking for Raging Phoenix (2009)

A violent gang is abducting and killing women around Thailand. Sanim and his friends, having had loved ones abducted, have joined together to break the gang of kidnappers. In a botched kidnap attempt, Deu is saved by Sanim's crew. After learning their unique martial arts style, Deu helps lure the gang into an epic battle to save the women across Thailand.


- 



He is still in love with Pai—his fiancée who was abducted by the Jaguar Gang three years before, during what was supposed to be their wedding.
The Jaguar gang only abducts women with a certain "smell", a smell that Deu has, which they use to make a special perfume
Sanim then sacrifices himself for Pai and lets go of Deu's hand. Raging Phoenix Wikipedia






Awesome, thank you madmada.

Happy to help !
